# Looking for road area - shapefile, UK

Tags: shapefile, data, road, united-kingdom

Does anyone know where you can download the road networks for the UK, outlining the whole road. I have found many shapefiles for just the road network/link showing a singular narrow line, but I am looking for where I can download the road data that contains pixels for all of the road (like the image below). I tried vector data from OS Maps which is what the image is off below but it just given the narrow single line, not the whole road.

[image: example]

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. Data requests are off-topic in our *problem-solving* site. [opendata.se] might be a more appropriate choice.

Comment: I think you will need to purchase the [OS highway data](https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/products/os-mastermap-highways-network-roads) to get road widths, though they still aren't polygons but attributed lines I think.

Comment: @IanTurton might be right. But to be honest, I doubt that road area polygons are available anywhere. In Poland for example, in the official GUGIK BDOT 10k data sets, the roads are represented as lines with width as attribute. OpenstreetMap has `width` attribute for some highways, see https://overpass-turbo.eu/s/1Ja3 or even roads as areas somewhere: https://overpass-turbo.eu/s/1Ja6